# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have seen this everywhere and tried multiple solutions, but it never worked for me.
This is the important parts of my code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")
    channel = bot.get_channel("The ID I don't want to share") # get the channel
    await channel.send("Passed")
```

I would really like to know why it isn't working. It gives me the full Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Nutzer/Documents/Programming/discord/main.py", line 125, in on_member_join
    await channel.send("Passed")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I also tried await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel("The ID I don't want to share"), 'OI MATES, gather around for ' + member.name + " joined our server.") as an await thing but it gave me the following Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Nutzer/Documents/Programming/discord/main.py", line 124, in on_member_join
    await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel("The ID I don't want to share"), 'OI MATES, gather around for ' + member.name + " joined our server.")
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

I did hear, that there was some kind of update on discord.py one has to do, as this is supposed to be some kind rewrite code. I do not know if I have to do it and am trying to avoid it, since im afraid of any change ruining the rest of my code.

Im thankfull for anything.

P.S. Yes there is a rest of code dedicated to incoming messages. It is fully functional and now I am trying to add a wellcoming message for new members.

Comment: IDs should be integers, not strings.

Comment: Well, now I feel very stupid. Thank you tho. (DO YOU KNOW HOW MANY HOURS I SAT HERE TRYING TO MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM thanks)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' ,when I try to send a message with a bot to a specific discord channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511899/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-send-when-i-try-to-send-a)

Answer (score 1):

As always, it was just my stupidity.
I put the Id as a string once because it didn't work on integers before and I thought it's due to that.
THE ID HAS TO AN INTIGER
I was wrong. TheFungusAmong was right.

Comment: Imma accept this in two days and close the question